# Creating chart with horizontal line

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet , where I have a pivot table. From the pivot table, I am generating chart. My sheet consist of two pivot table and  two charts respectively.

From the pivot table, from my column field "Target", I would like to draw a horizontal line on the value. Could some one help me, how I can mention the range and draw a horizontal line for my column field target. I searched through net, I could not find mentioning the range for a pivot table.

Also, I get an automation error in my Source data in the line

> `.SetSourceData pt`

Below Is the code I am using to generate my chart from pivot table

```
Sub chart()
Dim cht As Chart
Dim stable As PivotTable
Dim pt, sh

      If ActiveSheet.PivotTables.count = 0 Then Exit Sub
         Set stable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(2)
         Set pt = stable.TableRange1
         Set sh = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=250, _
         Width:=400, Top:=20, Height:=250)
         sh.Select
         Set cht = ActiveChart       
              With cht
               .SetSourceData pt
               .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
              End With
         cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "Average of Red"
         cht.SeriesCollection(1).HasDataLabels = True
         cht.SeriesCollection(2).HasDataLabels = True
         cht.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
         cht.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         cht.HasTitle = True
         cht.ChartTitle.Text = " Result 2017"
End Sub
```

[image: This is how I would like to have my chart. But with the title]

[image: this is how my second Pivot table look like. And from the column Target I would like to have the horizontal line]

Comment: Can you provide a screen print of your sheet and also how you want it to look?

Comment: Sure I will provide now

Comment: @Zac  I have added the screenshots for your reference.

Comment: @Zac could you help me in adding a horizontal line ?

Comment: Try this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1265-excel-add-average-line-to-chart.html. If that doesn't help, there is this as well: http://www.exceldashboardtemplates.com/3-ways-to-create-vertical-lines-in-an-excel-line-chart/

Comment: @Zac Thank you for your references. I already tried them. I have a pivot table and I am not able to define a range to add a new series to it.

Comment: @Zac I tried recording a macro but it dint work as well .

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. I think the difference is that you are driving your chart from Pivot table whereas I am using the range to create the chart (gives same results). If you try to use your range to create the chart, you can then easily create an 'Average' line in your chart following the first link in my initial comment

Comment: @Zac Exactly you understood my issue. Could you tell me how I can specify the range from a pivot table. Because this is the part what I am looing for , I searched through net, But I could not find a promising answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-PivotChart-c1b1e057-6990-4c38-b52b-8255538e7b1c 

Follow these steps:

- Click anywhere on the pivot table to show the pivot table menu items in the ribbon
- Click `Analyze` tab in the ribbon
- Now click on `PivotChart`
- This will open `Insert Chart` window. Select the type of chart you want and click `OK` button. This will create the chart
- From the chart, click on the series you want to display as a line and right click on it
- From the displayed menu, select `Change Series Chart Type...` option. This will open `Change Chart Type` window
- Series are listed at the bottom right of the window. For each series, there is a dropdown box. Click on the dropdown next to the series you want to change and select the `Line` chart type
- Click the `OK` button to close `Change Chart Type` window

This will give you a line in your pivot chart

Answer (score 1):

This is how to fix it:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=pt
.ChartType = xlColumnStacked
```

`:=` is used, when you specify the name of the argument that you pass. In this case the argument's name is `Source`

Comment: Thank you. My automation error is solved . but how can I add a horizontal line#

Comment: it can been static as well. because my target is 8% everytime